# How can I set a footer in a page to work both on PWA and a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a PWA and making it responsive has been a real challenge.

I'm trying to create a footer for my page, so I created these classes

```
#root {
 height:100vh;
}

.provider-container {
    padding: 3rem 1rem 4rem 1rem;
    height: 90%;
    border-radius: 0 0 1rem 1rem;
}

.footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    height: 4rem;
    background: white;
}
```

This is how my html looks like

```
<body>
 <div id="root">
  <div>Some content....</div>
  <div className="footer">footer</div>
 </div>
</body>
```

This works when I'm debbuging. The idea was that using the same value for the height of the footer and the padding-bottom of the container I could fit everything. When you add the page to the homescreen and open the app, it works.
**However, when I open the page using the browser, the container goes beyond its limit. Part of the content is placed behind the footer, as if the footer of the browser was part of the viewport.** 
I think the image below will help to understand. 
I could just change the content of the page, making everything small, removing some margins, but the problem is that when I open the app without the browser (opening from homescreen), everything will look way smaller.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using Bootstrap, it is built to aid responsiveness.

Comment: I'm new to PWS, but in standard html to refer to a class you use `class='footer'` not `className='footer'`.

Comment: @ElysianStorm I'm using bootstrap, but the thing is that when I open the app in a browser, the footer of the browser pushes my footer up, but the container stills the same size.

Comment: @imvain2 I'm using 'className' because it's a React App

Comment: Just a guess, maybe changing `position: absolute` to `relative` of the `footer` might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> Part of the content is placed behind the footer, as if the footer of the browser was part of the viewport.

This is the expected behaviour when an nodeElement is **absolute**. It no longer flows with the rest of the DOM layout. Therefore if there is limited screen space the rest of the items will re-flow and scroll but the absolute item will stay where it is.

It's possible the behaviour seem different for the PWA because of the size of the window / viewport.

The screenshot seems to be made on a laptop / desktop. Verify that the viewport width for both cases is the same.

If you want the footer to be at the bottom but scroll with the rest of the page if the content needs to scroll, you can do so with JS.